# Sending web requests between containers

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am using the built-in docker compose capabilities in visual studio for trying to learn more about modern microservice architecture. I have created 3 small projects.

- Gateway
- TenantService
- IdentiryProvider

All of these are .NET minimal APIs.

What I am trying to achieve is that only the Gateway is accessible from the "outside world" (read: the browser on the host) and the other services are simply called from that container.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  gateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Gateway/Dockerfile
    networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
    ports:
    - "3000"

  identityprovider:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}identityprovider
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: IdentityProvider/Dockerfile
    networks:
    - backend
    ports:
    - "3002"

  tenantservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}tenantservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TenantService/Dockerfile
    networks:
    - backend
    ports:
    - "3001"

networks:
  frontend:
    name: frontend
    external: true
  backend:
    name: backend
    external: true
```

In my gateway, I have tried to define a super simple endpoint to call the `tenantservice`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(
    "tenant",
    client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://tenantservice:3001/");
    }
    );

// Add services to the container.
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    return "gateway";
});

app.MapGet("/tenant/", (IHttpClientFactory clientFactory) =>
{
    using var client = clientFactory.CreateClient("tenant");
    var result = client.GetStringAsync("tenant").Result;
    return Results.Ok(result);
});

app.Run();
```

But I get connection refused when sending the request.
I have tried `localhost`,`host.docker.internal`, and `tenantservice`, all over http and https. But the result remains the same.

I can also call all services on their host ports from my browser(not sure if I can restrict that from the host machine)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag as this is not a question about using the Visual Studio application.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Sure, I thought it might have been relevant that I am using the built-in docker support from visual studio :)

Comment: Can you try specifying `container_name` under `image` (e.g. `container_name: tenantservice`)?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Same result

Comment: Is `tenantservice` definitely running on port 3001? Setting `ports` only exposes that port, but if the service in the container is listening on a different port then it won't work.

Comment: On which port do the containers host their APIs? In your docker-compose.yml, you specify port "3000"; most likely, your APIs are hosted on 80 or 5000 or the like. So there needs to be a mapping, e.g. "3000:80" or the like. Maybe you can start with the gateway container and add a route that returns a version.

Comment: Sorry, but I can see all containers have a host port and local port, in the "containers" window. I am unsure how I check which port a container is running on.  But the "output" log does say 
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://[::]:443
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://[::]:443
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://[::]:80

Comment: OK, so it's listening on 443 and 80. So you need something like `- "3001:443"` to tell it to listen on 3001 and route traffic into the container to port 443.

Comment: Hm still getting the same error.

Comment: if your containers are meant for internal use then remove "ports" all-together. Leave only the gateway exposed. Also don't use https to talk between containers. Only http is enought for your case. Then call `http://tenantservice`

Comment: @Mihai I still cannot get it to work "connection refused" still

Comment: As it stands, this is a big question and IMHO it is not easy to help you with it on SO because it would require building a prototype from scratch. Maybe you can try to start with one container (the gateway?) in a docker-compose.yml. After you have published its API successfully and can reach it from the outside, you can add another and continue with the communication between the containers. One step at a time - if you need help with the steps, SO is a better fit.

Comment: @MattBaech Did you remove "app.UseHttpsRedirection();"? also can you attach the logs where you see the connection refused?

Comment: ´@Mihai I did. the GetStringAsync just raises: System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused (tenantservice:64235))'

Comment: @Mihai But I can see that the actual port it tries to connect to is the host port of the container - is that not wrong?

Comment: @MattBaech it connects to what you tell it to connect to. If the application runs in the browser (like javascript) then they connect to the host (so to the host port that is mapped to a container port). If the application runs in the container (so the request goes from the browser but the actual code runs in the container) then only the internal container port is needed. If I look at your error then inside the tenant service container your app should run on 64235, not 80. Otherwise your connection string should expllicitely specify the port (is that a default maybe....?)

Comment: @Mihai I am pretty sure it's a default, but I can't figure out how to overwrite visual studio's default ports for containers (they seem to change every single time i start debugging)

Comment: @Mihai Wow - visual studio had an docker-compose-override.yml which only had the container ports set, so it just ran the containers on random ports